# Every injective map $f: \{1,\cdots,n\} \to \{1,\cdots,n\}$ is bijective, proof-verification

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I'm not sure whether I forget something by proofing the following statement:

Statement: Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Every injective map $f: \{1,\cdots,n\} \to \{1,\cdots,n\}$ is bijective.

Proof: Induction over $n$.

$n=1$: $\quad f:\{1\} \to \{1\}$ is bijective.

Assume now that the statement is true for an arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

We consider an injective map $f: \{1,\cdots,n+1\} \to \{1,\cdots,n+1\}$. First there exist an $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(k)=n+1$. Otherwise $f|_{\{1,\cdots,n\}}$ maps injectively from $\{1,\cdots,n\} \to \{1,...n\}$ and hence is bijective by the Induction hypothesis. But then there exist $j \in \{1,\cdots,n\}$ such that  $f_{|\{1,\cdots,n\}}(j)=f(n+1)$ since $f(n+1) \in \{1,\cdots,n\}$, a contradiction to the injectivity. This $k$ is unique (injectivity). Furthermore we can assume that $k\neq n+1$ (otherwise we are done: $f|_{\{1,\dots,n\}}$ maps to $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ and is injective and hence bijetive and $f$ maps $n+1$ to $n+1$).

Now we define $$g(j):=\left\{\begin{array}{lll} n+1, & j=f(n+1) \\
         f(n+1), & j=n+1\\ j&, \text{else} \end{array}\right. . $$
and $$h(j):=(g \circ f)(j)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll} n+1, & j=n+1 \\
         f(n+1), & j=k\\ f(j)&, \text{else} \end{array}\right.$$
$h$ is injective. This follows from the injectivity of $f$ and the uniqueness of $k$. By the induction hypothesis we can conclude that $$h|_{\{1,\dots,n\}}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} f(n+1) & j=k\\ f(j)&, \text{else} \end{array}\right.$$ is bijective.
But then there exist for every $m \in \{1,\cdots,n\}$ an $j \in \{1,\cdots,n\}$ with $f(j)=m$. Together with $f(k)=n+1$ we obtain that $f:\{1,\cdots,n+1\} \to \{1,\cdots,n+1\}$ is surjective and hence bijective.

Comment: I would say "Assume it is not surjective. Then, there is at least one element in the second set which is not an image of any element in the first set. Now since both sets have the same number of elements, two elements in the first set is mapped to the same element in the second set which contradicts the injectivitiy."

Comment: @VIVID I c'ant use the statement to proof the statement. I have to show that an injective map between two sets with the same cardinality is surjective

Comment: Did I do that? I assumed it was **not** a surjective map, then it led to a contradiction.

Comment: @VIVID Yes but you just reformulated the statement. Asking for an elementary proof of your reformulation would be the same task. The statement is evident. But I want to give an elementary proof .

Comment: The proof seems to be fine, even though I agree with @VIVID, that it is unnecessarily complicated.